# Writing to unix socket file as fast as possible

Tags: perl, socket, buffer, unix-sockets

I'm trying to write with perl to a unix socket file as fast as possible but failing on full message buffer. I tried autoflush and manual flush without success.

```perl
use IO::Select;
use IO::Socket::UNIX;

my $sock = IO::Socket::UNIX->new(
    Type => IO::Socket::SOCK_DGRAM,
    Peer => "/dev/log",
) or die "$!\n";
$sock->autoflush(1);  
my $sel = IO::Select->new($sock);
my $cnt = 0;
while(<>){
    $sel->can_write or die "1 line $cnt: $!\n";             
    $sock->say($_) or die "2 line $cnt: $!\n"; 
    $sock->flush or die "3 line $cnt: $!\n";
    $cnt++;
}
$sock->close();
```

The output is always `2 line 64: No buffer space available`

Update: I'm not fixed to Perl. Maybe there is some better way on sending to a socket on IBM AIX.

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to send more data faster to a network stack that is already
full will not work, as you have observed. At least it is less messy than
trying to pour more data down an already full bathroom drain. Anyways,
the sender here must wait until the condition clears, or perhaps the
buffers for the network stack can be increased, which will cause the
data to pool up somewhere else (in the septic tank of the kernel, so to
speak) until it can be processed. Also, datagram is not really known for
having a stream to flush, and the `$.` Perl variable already does the
work of your `$cnt`, so

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Errno ':POSIX';
use IO::Socket::UNIX;
use Time::HiRes 'usleep';

my $peer = shift || die "Usage: $0 /dev/log\n";

my $sock = IO::Socket::UNIX->new(
    Peer => $peer,
    Type => IO::Socket::SOCK_DGRAM,
) or die "socket failed '$peer': $!\n";

LINE: while (<>) {
    $sock->print($_) and next;
    if ($!{ENOBUFS}) {
        while (1) {
            # exponential backoff might be more typical and less rude
            # here, or the code could try to be smart about how long to
            # wait for, but that takes more code and more memory and
            # more effort on the part of the programmer
            usleep(128);
            $sock->print($_) and last;
            # PORTABILITY and there may be a bunch of different error
            # messages from trying to go too fast here with a full
            # buffer, check for them ...
            unless ($!{EMSGSIZE} or $!{ENOBUFS} or $!{ETIMEDOUT}) {
                my $errno = 0 + $!;
                die "print failed line $.: $! ($errno)";
            }
        }
    } else {
        my $errno = 0 + $!;
        die "print failed line $.: $! ($errno)";
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing I missed to write is faster-than-using-sleep-every-nth-loop. So this is not using a brute force approach but still sleep. I hoped there is a solution with select or wait-until-ready. Anyway, thanks I'll give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: It's working, but every solution with a random sleep doesn't fit into "as fast as possible" IMHO.

Comment: perhaps if the kernel had an interface where you could ask for N bytes (kernel: I'm busy right now so you can have 0, check again later) or better yet if the kernel could notify your program when it has N bytes for your program to play with within some timeframe (you would probably need to write that). or you could do this work within the kernel, but then interactivity might suffer a little if it's doing your thing "as fast as possible"